# Expectation of the number of games A or B wins?

Tags: probability

Assume player A, B throw a pair of fair dices in turn. Player A is the winner if the sum of two dices is 5 at the round he throw and player B is the winner if the sum of the dices is 9 at his turn. Once any one of the player achieve their number, the game end and he will become the winner.What is the expected number of rolls such that A or B wins

Comment: Why do you [slice your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/229658)? Anyway, here is an exercise: adapt the decomposition proof on the other page, to reach an answer to the present problem which avoids the use of series and the like.

Comment: It is asking different things, do you mean i have to ask on the same question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  what is the chance the game ends when A tosses-call it $a$?  what is the chance when B tosses-call it $b$?  The expectation is then $1\cdot a + 2(1-a)b + 3(1-a)(1-b)a +4(1-a)(1-b)(1-a)b + \ldots$ where I have written it (number of rounds)(chance to not end before that round)(chance to end that round)

Added:  A simpler approach is to let $n$ be the number of total rounds, with a round being a toss by A and maybe one by B.  You play another round with probability $(1-a)(1-b)$ so the expected number of rounds is $\frac 1{(1-a)(1-b)}$.  Given that you end on a particular round, you should be able to calculate the chance that A wins, and therefore the chance that you play only one game.

Comment: Is the chance the game ends when A tosses = the probability A wins?

Comment: @Mathematics:  it is the probability that A wins that time.  that is how I read your third sentence.

Comment: well, i think that's true but how do you solve that summation?? That form seems complicated

Comment: It is basically a geometric series with each term multiplied by $n$.  You could look at Eric Naslund's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53496/a-fast-way-for-computing-sum-limits-n-1100-n-times-2n/53497#53497) for guidance.

Comment: Is n geometric distributed? It seems the second approach is much faster.

Comment: @Mathematics:  Yes, $n$ is geometric.  Yes, I think the second is much faster.