# Probability of a person being first to obtain a head when three people are flipping coins

Tags: probability

A, B and C are people. They take turns flipping a coin with A flipping first, B second, C third..The winner is the one who first obtains a head. What is A's probability of winning?

What is the procedure for solving this problem?

Comment: You're asking for a slightly more general question than this one
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229658/probability-of-a-wins-the-game/229669#229669

Try to see if you can make something out of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we know that Player A won. The probability that he won on his first toss is $\frac 12$. The probability that he won on his second toss is $\frac 12 * \frac 12 * \frac 12 * \frac 12$ = $(\frac 12)^4$. (The first three $\frac 12$'s are the probability that A got tails, then B got tails, then C got tails, so that A may flip again). Using the same procedure, we see that the probability of player A winning on his third flip is $(\frac 12)^7$. We quickly see there is a pattern. Player A's total probability of winning is:
$$\frac 12,(\frac 12)^4,(\frac 12)^7,...(\frac 12)^{3n-2}$$
This is a geometric progression with $a=\frac 12$ and $r = \frac 18$. That means that the sum
$$S=\frac{a}{1-r}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{8}} = \frac{4}{7}$$
represents $P(A)$, the probability of player A wining.

We can do the same thing with player B and player C. Note that since player B goes second, he must count on player A getting tails the first time, which has a $\frac 12$ probability, so all we need to do is multiply $\frac 12$ with each term in the series probided above for A. That means that $P(B)$ is simply $\frac 12$ of the sum given for A, which would make $P(B) = \frac 12 * \frac 47 = \frac 27$.

Same thing with player C. He must count on the first two players getting tails, which each have a $\frac 12$ probability, giving $P(C) = \frac 14 P(A) = \frac 14 * \frac 47 = \frac 17$.

In the end, $P(A) = \frac 47, P(B) = \frac 27, P(C) = \frac 17$. Adding up all the probabilities gives you $1$.

As Ross describes in the commnets below, we know that $P(B) = \frac 12 P(A),P(C) = \frac 14 P(A),P(A)+P(B)+P(C) = P(A) + \frac 12 P(A) + \frac 14 P(A)= 1$ and so on.

Comment: In fact, you can argue simply that $P(B)=\frac 12 P(A)$ as if A throws tails B is in the same position.  Then $P(C)=\frac 14 P(A)$.  This is what you did in your check.

Comment: Very nice cheers.

Comment: Ross, Thank you for pointing that out. That is actually what I would have done. Noting those equalities and noting that the sum of all the probabilities equal 1 will give you each of the probabilities.

Comment: @Ross, I didn't understand what you said, can you please explain that a bit more? What I see is that the probability of A, B & C winning depends on the 'loss probability' of (BC), (AC) and (AB) respectively. So why should probability of B winning be half that of A?

Comment: @MrReality:  $A$ has some chance $P(A)$ to win based on the fact that he throws first.  If $A$ tosses heads he wins immediately.  Otherwise, with probability $\frac 12$ he tosses tails and $B$ gets to throw.  At this point, $B$ is in the same position $A$ was in at the start of the game, so his chance of winning given that $A$ throws tails must be $P(A)$.  The chance $A$ throws tails is $\frac 12$ so the overall chance $B$ wins is $\frac 12P(A)$